# Remove characters not in string variable as pattern in Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string variable that I want to use as part of the pattern of valid characters in Regex.Replace:

```
string unreservedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";
string input = "gzaHQ6PKUgQjXP+/dajkl==";
```

Is there a simple (hopefully one liner) to replace the characters in `input` that do not exist in `unreservedChars`?

Comment: FYI, a small matter, but `Regex` is part of .NET. It is not part of C#. This is different from JavaScript, for instance, which has built-in Regex support.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try the short-hand character ranges:

```
// returns "gzaHQPKUgQjXPdajkl"
Regex.Replace("gzaHQ6PKUgQjXP+/dajkl==", @"[^a-zA-Z0-9-_.~]", "");
```

Comment: Nice answer -- don't forget to add the digits

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It doesn't look like there is a one liner to use the `unreservedChars` variable (`Regex.Escape` only escaped the `.` but not the `-`, `_`, or `~`).  This definitely got me closer to it though!